# File dialog doesn't show any files

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to open some .txt files but after executing:

```
file = askopenfilename(initialfile='Sin título.txt', defaultextension=".txt",filetypes=[("All files","."),("Text Documents","*.text")])
```

The file dialog appears but doesn't show any files that I'm sure are, and should be, in that folder

Comment: Are you aware the dialog will open in the current working directory, which may be different than where the script is located?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, I also checked other folders to where I'm sure are .txt files and the problem continues.

Comment: Please do a bit more to explain the problem. For example, show us the output of `ls *` (or the equivalent for your OS) in the current working directory. By the way,  your "All Files" pattern doesn't do what you think -- it will only match files whose name match a dot. You probably want that pattern to be `"*"`

Comment: yeah, it was that. I added the * and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There were missing two * surrounding the dot in `[("All files",".")` . So it would be `[("All files","*.*")`